# Why is my Lambda function only sometimes writing to my DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

The objective: Create a URL redirector for mobile app links to the corresponding app stores using AWS Lambda, API Gateway and DynamoDB e.g. if an iPhone user visits the URL, it should redirect them to the App Store page for a particular app.

I've managed to get this to work for the most part but whenever I invoke the Lambda function more than once on any device, it carries out the redirect but it won't insert a record into my DynamoDB table. If I clear browser data, it'll insert the record until it doesn't the next time the function is invoked.

Is it a problem with my code, my API Gateway settings or something else? Or any suggestions on how I can debug the issue?

Lambda code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({ region: "eu-west-2", apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // Set up global redirect URL variable to be returned in the response
    var redirectURL = "https://jifflr.com/";
    
    // Set up global os variable to insert into DynamoDB
    var os = "other";
    
    // Get user agent info from event header
    const userAgent = event.headers["User-Agent"];
    
    // Change redirectURL according to user agent
    switch (true) {
        case userAgent.includes("iPhone"):
            os = "iOS";
            redirectURL = "https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/jifflr/id1434427409";
            break;
        case userAgent.includes("iPad"):
            os = "iOS";
            redirectURL = "https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/jifflr/id1434427409";
            break;
        case userAgent.includes("Android"):
            os = "android";
            redirectURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.jifflr.app&hl=en_GB";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    // Define response parameters
    const response = {
        statusCode: 301,
        body: JSON.stringify(os),
        headers: { Location: redirectURL }
    };
    
    // Initialise insert data
    var params = {
        TableName: "jifflr",
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: "TOTAL",
        Item: {
            "id": { S: context.awsRequestId }, 
            "os": { S: os }
        }
    };
    
    // Insert into database
    try{
        const data = await dynamoDB.putItem(params).promise();
        response.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch(err){
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        response.body = JSON.stringify(err);
    }
    
    return response;
};
```

Overview of the DynamoDB table:
[image: DynamoDB table overview]

Comment: Hi Raf, what are the PK and SK keys of the DynamoDB Table?

Comment: Hi, my only PK is 'id' and I have no SKs. I'll add a screenshot of the table's overview to the question.

Comment: try printing params in the log and see if `context.awsRequestId` is being duplicated somehow?

Comment: Have you considered a caching issue, i.e. the browser caches the response from the first request and redirects you immediately upon subsequent requests? Can you confirm that the lambda is actually called every time you access the url?

Comment: @Asdfg I can't look at the logs because the CloudWatch metrics show that the Lambda function isn't even being invoked after the first time. I think Ben is right, it seems like a caching issue. I'll see if there's any solutions to this on SO or elsewhere but further inputs would still be appreciated.

Comment: If you are sending POST requests, browser should not cache them. Are you sending POST request from your front end?

Comment: It seems your status code 301 is the problem. Try changing it to 302. 301 is permanent redirect while 302 is temporary redirect. Your browser is cashing the response and knows it will be redirected so it doesn’t bother call the api. It just redirects. Changing it to 302 should fix the problem. Or use 307.

Comment: Interesting use of dynamic, fluid case values.

Comment: @jarmod I think the keys in the params object need to be PascalCase but other than that I try to stick to camelCase - I didn't realise how bad it was until you mentioned it haha.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to your switch statement. It's an inversion of the typical switch statement (and not even possible in most programming languages). You're switching on a constant value and the cases are dynamic values (and they can change each time the switch/case is executed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your status code 301 is the problem. Try changing it to 302. 301 is permanent redirect while 302 is temporary redirect. Your browser is cashing the response and knows it will be redirected so it doesn’t bother call the api. It just redirects. Changing it to 302 should fix the problem.

Comment: Nice! I guess I need to do a bit more reading around the status codes. Also, I agree that it should be a POST request but some reason the assignment specifically asks me to use a GET request. Thanks.